# IE Glitch on Logo

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a glitch on Internet Explorer (all editions, including 8+), where the logo is not displaying correctly. It is displaying perfectly on all other browsers, but the glitch is not being rectified by the file ie.css (which I believe should fix the existing issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The website is as below:

http://www.taray-investments.com/

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Well, IE is famous for its problems with SVG displaying. Dig it that direction and maybe you'll find something

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to a site or an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Also can you add more details about what is going wrong with logo, most people don't have access to IE atm.

Comment: If you want provide compatibility to old IE web browsers I recommend you to transform the logo from .svg to a transparent png. I can see that desktop version logo (The website is responsive) has a fixed size, so you can easily convert it to png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Your code is only loading the ie.css if the version is less than or equal to 8

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

That will load if it's IE at all.

Of course as suggested using PNG instead of SVG is your main goal for old IE versions but I don't believe your site works under IE8- correctly anyway and it's (imo) ridiculous for clients to expect support for IE8- anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess what is going wrong, but here are some possible problems:
1) Logo is not scaling correctly, in latest versions of IE
2) I saw some transitions in your code, so this might be the issue.
3) Any other svv background related bugs.

First can be fixed with svg inline attributes.
Second and 3rd are unfixable thou.
If you want to suppot any versions of IE older than 11, i suggest using .png instead of svg.